# Google Apps Admin account username and password lost

Tags: google-workspace, account-recovery

I created an Google Apps business (free edition) account for my friend back in 2012. After that we never logged in to that account. Now today when tried logging back in we don't remember username or password. Google does not provide support if you're free business apps user.

How can I recover this account. I do not think I created any secondary email for that domain or I don't even remember recovery email address if I would have specified that time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try visiting this URL:

```
https://admin.google.com/example.com/ForgotAdminAccountInfo
```

Where it has `example.com` in the URL change that to your Google Apps domain. This will give you a captcha to fill out and send instructions on changing your username and/or password.